# Error when migrating to macOS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a web app using React and Redux on the front end and Node on the back end with Express and MongoDB.

My app runs fine on my Windows machine. Today, I cloned the repository onto my macOS device and ran `npm install` inside the client and the root directory and then I tried running the application to find this error message pop up:

[image: Error message]

I'm not sure what this error message means and stack trace displays that the error originates from Redux inside the `node_modules` folder, which is code I did not write or touch. Here is the repo: https://github.com/furtivepygmy/devconnector

I'm new here, so please go easy on me. I always face issues when moving my workspace between macOS and Windows, however I can't seem to fix this one. Is there something I need to do when migrating between operating systems?

Comment: Do you have the latest versions of your libraries in your `package.json` ?

Comment: Are you using `redux dev tools`?

Comment: Okay, the error is gone. I hadn't added the redux dev tools chrome extension until after I posted this. Thanks @robe007. I understand that now that this line of code was causing the issue:

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

Comment: Tamam, iyi şanslar arkadaşım !